# AxWindowsMediaPlayer - black screen

Tags: c#, windows, media-player

I'm building a desktop app in c# that uses AxWindowsMediaPlayer and is working nice, but when i kill explorer.exe (because i'm trying simulate kiosk mode on windows 10 home) the AxWindowsMediaPlayer control doesn't play, only shows a black screen.

What can i do to put it work?
Or any alternative for AxWindowsMediaPlayer?

I just need something to simulate screen saver; slide show to pictures and sometimes play some videos with no play/pause/stop... controls.

Thank you

Comment: What OS are you running? It's working perfect for me on Win 8.1 Pro

Comment: Win 10 Home. Work nice without explorer.exe running?

Comment: Yes works perfectly. Maybe the problem is because of Win 10.

Comment: Perhaps. I will try with new app with only the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line resolved the issue.

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using DirectX rather than the WMP control, you'll have more control and probably less overhead.

See:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PlayingVideo11242005002218AM/PlayingVideo.aspx

Comment: Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback is not available to add as .NET reference so i find the dll on C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback\1.0.2902.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll even so nothing append when i call video.Play() after set Owner...
Meanwhile i found this article [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8277/Problems-in-the-AudioVideoPlayback-namespace-of-ma)...